# Do you place files processing logic in repositories? (Using generic repository and UoW pattern with EF)?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have a question.

So I know that generic repository pattern and EF work very well when you need to work with Databse only.

However in my case I need to load data from files and into the Database using Entity Framework and Generic Repository pattern.

So here is my question. Where does the logic for loading file data into EF entities belong?

Should I make this logic a part of each specific repository for specific entity?

Or should I have a separate business class that uploads File data into EF entities separately of the Repository?

I hope that is clear enough.

Comment: If I undestand good your question is about storing files in a folder inside of application or in the database?

Comment: No, its about whether I should implement file data conversion logic (to EF entities) inside of the repository classes or its own business logic classes. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So here is my question. Where does the logic for loading file data
>   into EF entities belong?

My opinion is that it belongs in your repositories.  Your data-stores aren't always going to be databases.  They can be files, internal and external services, excel sheets, etc.

> Should I make this logic a part of each specific repository for
>   specific entity?

Yes

> Or should I have a separate business class that uploads File data into
>   EF entities separately of the Repository?

I think this is unnecessary.  Business classes should have business logic only.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer. One thing I wanted to clarify is: I am aware that data store can be other stores besides the database. However I was assuming this is only if you use Repository for a specific access, either to files, or databases or whatever. However what about when my repository needs to access both the file AND the database? Doesn't it violate separation of concerns? Isnt repository supposed to have 1 data-store only?

Comment: @Tanuki...I don't think it violates SOC.  A repository serves an intermediary function - coordinating the data access.  In your case, consolidating the file and DB access in the repository is a nice implementation of SOC and the single reponsibility principle, too.  A repository can be anything you want it to be.  I don't think it should be 1-to-1 per data-store.  Lots of times you'll need to mash-up data between source and that would be messy with separate repositories per data-store.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, that answers my question completely!